# Two Tables, Cannot retrieve entity config on second table when joining tables

Tags: magento-enterprise, module, mysql

## Problem

I'm creating a simple module that contains two tables named:

- `city_faq`
- `city_faq_section`

I'm having a difficult time joining `city_faq` with `city_faq_section`.  Each time I try to do so, I receive the following error:

`Can't retrieve entity config: city_faq/city_faq_section`.

## Additional Information

## UPDATE:

After a few hours of debugging, it appears that the problem may stem from the model calling the collection, `City_Faq_Model_Faq`.  In its constructor, I have `$this->_init('city_faq/faq');`, but this may not be correct.  Would this cause the above error?

#### Here is my join call:

```
/** $this refers to City_Faq_Model_Resource_Faq_Collection **/
    $this->join(
        array('sections' => $this->getTable('section')),
        'main_table.section_id = sections.section_id',
        array('sections.*')
    )
    ->setOrder('sections.sort', self::SORT_ORDER_ASC)
    ->setOrder('main_table.sort', self::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
```

Clearly, I'm choking on `$this->getTable('section')` - however, if add the following right above the join call, I see the correct table in the log file (`city_faq_section`), so it appears that the config is read correctly.

```
    Mage::log($this->getTable('section'))
```

The pertinent section of my config.xml looks like this:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <City_Faq>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </City_Faq>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <city_faq>
                <class>City_Faq_Helper</class>
            </city_faq>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <city_faq>
                <class>City_Faq_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>city_faq_resource</resourceModel>
            </city_faq>
            <city_faq_resource>
                <class>City_Faq_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <faq>
                        <table>city_faq</table>
                    </faq>
                    <section>
                        <table>city_faq_section</table>
                    </section>
                </entities>
            </city_faq_resource>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <city_faq>
                <class>City_Faq_Block</class>
            </city_faq>
        </blocks>
        <resources>
            <city_faq_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>City_Faq</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </city_faq_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

Both tables (`city_faq` and `city_faq_section`) exist.  I'm sure I'm missing something silly.  What's interesting, is when completing the join call, the class `City_Faq_Model_Resource_Faq` is instantiated but `City_Faq_Model_Resource_Section` is not.  This leads me to believe that this is the issue.

### Things I've tried

- I've tried  `$this->getTable('city_faq/section')`
- I've even tried setting directly via `$this->getTable('city_faq_section')`

### File Structure

```
-City
    -Faq
        -Model
            -Resource
                - Faq
                    . Collection.php
                . Faq.php
                . Section.php
            . Faq.php
            . Section.php

        -sql
            -ciy_faq_setup
                . mysql4-install-0.2.0.php
        -etc
            . config.xml
```

Comment: Try with `$this->getTable('city_faq/section')` instead of `$this->getTable('section')`

Comment: Thanks @Marius - Tried that too (should have mentioned that), but the error is still the same and `Mage::log($this->getTable('city_faq/section'));` still outputs the correct table `city_faq_section`.  I'll update my question with things I've tried.

Comment: Strange. Are you sure the problem does not come from an other piece of code? Just asking to make sure.

Comment: I guess it must be - The installer script uses `$installer->getTable('city_faq/section')` and the table is installed correctly as well. I'll keep digging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a fairly silly mistake.  Since my module will be similar in structure to the `Mage_Poll` plugin, I used that as a reference.

Rather than:

```
$this->join(
        array('sections' => $this->getTable('section')),
        ...
```

It should have been:

```
$this->getSelect()->join(
        array('sections' => $this->getTable('section')),
        ...
```

Now it makes sense why basically everything in the module was working, except for the join statement.  Aye...